# Laravel Eloquent Get the data of foreign key also

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to get the data of a Model and also the data of the foreign key in the Model

For Example:

A Post Model has a user_id as a foreign key. How can I write an Eloquent query so that I can get the data of a Post and in place of the user_id, I get the data of the user_id ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `with` method when querying your post to include the user.

```php
$post = Post::with('user')->first();
// or
$posts = Post::with('user')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

At Post model

```
public function user(){
   return $this->belongsTo(User::class,'user_id');
}
```

Now at your PostController

Guess you have a method which is use for showing post

```
public function show($id){
   $post = Post::query()->findOrFail($id);
}
```

Now if you want to access which user posted then there has two ways.

Way 1 :

```
public function show($id){
   $post = Post::query()->with('user')->findOrFail($id);
}
```

Way 2 :

```
public function show($id){
   $post = Post::query()->findOrFail($id);
   echo $post->user->firstName; 
}
```

Note :

If you just write $post->user then it will show/return User table according to user_id column.

If you want to access these user row column then . Simply $post->user->column_name;

Enjoy Coding.